# How do I get admin.StackedInline or admin.TabularInline like feel in my own views?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Consider the simple Poll example in the Django Tutorial example in Djnagoproject web site. Once you use admin.StackedInline or TabularInline, you get a nice interface which allows you create a neat Poll application.

If I need to provide same look, feel and functionality in my own custom views, what should I do. For eg: I want to let users create polls, but they don't have  access to the admin section, but we can provide a view like "/create/polls/".

Any ideas, code, pointers will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

[Inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).